# Windows explorer taking almost all RAM

Tags: windows-10, memory, windows-explorer

I am using windows 10 and RAM is 4GB. After starting laptop suddenly RAM usage is building up to 100% and system is freezing. When i checked task manager it is showing Windows Explorer is taking almost all RAM. I am not able to do anything on my Laptop that's why I am not able to post the screenshot also. What should i do now can somebody tell?

Comment: can you repro this? If yes, reboot Windows, install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **CPU usage**, **VirtualAlloc usage**, **Resident Analysis** and click **start** Now capture 2-3 minutes of the memory usage grow and click on **Save** to store the report into an ETL file. Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.

Comment: @magicandre1981 i checked it again it is freezing when I'm trying to open any folder or file and in task manager accross windows explorer it is showing 3GB RAM usage after a minute the usage is coming down. But again when I'm trying to open any other file then same problem is occurring.

Comment: Here is the link of that etl zip file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6CRRMWk1IhBaUhucnhpQWtaVnc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: the trace is corrupted. I see you still use the version from July 2015. Make the upgrade to the november update 1511 and look if the issue is gone.

Comment: Version of what?

Comment: Version of Windows?

Comment: Windows 10 got a large update in november called version 1511 - build 10586. Is it not offered via WindowsUpdate? if not, download the Home Single Language ISO, mount it, run setup.exe and select update: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/software-download/techbench (make a complete PC backup first so if something wents wrong you can restore the device)

Comment: In my settings it is showing update for windows 10 for x64 based system(KB3173427) and other updates are also available. Also I can see version 1511 is waiting to install.

Comment: no, this is an update to the servicing stack to improve setup of updates.

Comment: It is showing Windows 10 Home Single Language, version 1511, 10586 is waiting to install state.

Comment: ok, let WindowsUpdate install this version 1511 and look if you still have the issue. if yes, capture a new trace

Comment: Ok I'll let you know.

Comment: Hey.. I have updated to latest windows but the problem is still there, here is the link of the latest trace: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6CRRMWk1IhBN081Tl9vaUpRM2M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you haven't run WindowsUpdate. I see you use the older 10586.162. Yesterday a new update was released. Also the ETL is corrupted again. I can't see how much memory is used by Explorer. Run this command instead: **xperf.exe -on PROC_THREAD+LOADER+PROFILE+INTERRUPT+DPC+DISPATCHER+CSwitch+POWER+FOOTPRINT+VIRT_ALLOC+MEMINFO+VAMAP+REFSET+MEMINFO_WS+NETWORKTRACE -stackwalk Profile+CSwitch+ReadyThread+VirtualAlloc+VirtualFree -buffersize 2048 -MaxFile 2048 -FileMode Circular && timeout -1 && xperf -d C:\MemoryUsage.etl**

Comment: Can i send you a screenshot of the task manager

Comment: Here are the links of the photos: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6CRRMWk1IhBNGkyeFJNYlNZVk0   and   https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6CRRMWk1IhBWi05YkYzb0diOXc

Comment: I have run the windows update correctly. And it is showing up to date. Also the command you have given is not working. All went correctly while etl file was generating. I dont know why it is corrupted. Above are the links of the photos of RAM usage and performance when i am opening any file or folder.

Comment: here is the last update: http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/secu/2016/07/windows10.0-kb3172985-x64_006b20fc4c418499afa25248edacff2ef7dab963.msu

Comment: the command must be one line: http://pastebin.com/r0rvcMJq

Comment: have you tried the xperf command?

Comment: Hey.. I have updated my pc with some cumulative updates and it's working fine now. I forget to inform.

Comment: ok, post this answer and post which version you now use (run winver.exe to see it) and which update (KB number) was installed

Comment: again, please add the KBnumber of the update you have installed and post which Buildnumber you use (10586.xxx) so that others know which update they have to install if they have the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I have updated my pc with version 1511 (OS Build 10586.494) KB number is KB3172985. My system is working properly. The issue of RAM is resolved by this update.

Answer (score 2):

This worked temporary for me. After a system restart, it was taking lots of RAM like before.
Had to do the steps again

I had the same problem on Windows 10 with 8GB RAM, and restarting Explorer didn't work for me. The following may work:

- Open Task Manager
- On the Details tab, find `explorer.exe`
- Right-click on it and choose *End process tree*
- Confirm *End process tree*

Some windows might close; the task bar also disappears.

- Now in Task Manager's File menu, click on *Run new task*.
- Type `explorer.exe` in the bar. Click OK.

Comment: Windows 10 includes the ability to restart Explorer directly in the task manager without having to close it and restart it. Also, OP notes this issue occurs when they very first turn the computer on, which means that simply restarting explorer.exe is less likely to be a fix as it has actually just started itself.

Comment: @music2myear restarting didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Open task manager and restart Explorer at the bottom of the list. (Try to remove external devices before doing it)

Restarting Explorer is similar to a system restart.

It's possible that a process is running in background or a corrupted one causing this issue.

If it still doesn't work try cleaning thumbnail cache.

Open This PC (my computer) and right click on C Drive and select properties. There perform a **disk cleanup** to remove temp files, thumbnails and other cache.

See if it works.

Comment: Tried that also nothing happened

Comment: In such case try to find out if any other service is running in background or try this command in CMD (ADMIN)  `sfc /scannow` it will check for corrupted system files and will repair them automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It often helps to diagnose problems with Task Manager.  That does take some resources, but is very manageable. I keep Task Manager running in the background at all times. If a program freezes and becomes unresponsive, I will close it there instead of booting the machine. Often, after using a CPU intensive program, such as photo editing, I will need to reboot Windows Explorer from there, instead of booting the machine.

Press CTRL, ALT, and DEL (Delete) at the same time.  This is known as the "MS Three Finger Salute" and has been used since Windows 95. You will get a Blue Screen with several options.  Choose the bottom option which will be "Task Manager".

Task Manager will show every resource currently loaded into the memory.  Even if they are resting and not using any resources.

ClicK on "Performance" tab.  This shows your CPU usage.  At the bottom of the page click on "Open Resource Monitor".  That opens a separate box that shows which programs are actually using the resources. This can be very important in isolating run away programs and malware.

Answer (score 0):

(Temporarily) Try: Windows Search > "Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows" > "Adjust for best performance" > "Apply" > "OK".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Old thread - a persistent issue

After a Windows refresh, some settings get reverted and problems can come back. Engineers allegedly fixed the explorer memory leak for Win11 Insiders, but the patch is not live yet and many users are still on Win10.

So what can you do about it?

- Restart explorer.exe in Task Manager to debug it
- Modify Explorer Folder Options to prevent it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap79E.png)

Answer (score -3):

> Try those they may help you

- you can open explorer for up to 10 min and then restart your PC if didn't work open your Cmd as administrator and type **sfc /scannow** if didn't work there is the last a temp and its to open a New Text Document and text on it from 100 to 500 letters and stay on it for 3 - 5 min and hope it works if not try shutting down your PC and stay like 1 day or above and come back and open your PC again that what i had :D
- if nothing did work from the above try to end explorer.exe and wait for 10 min and run it again with clicking on `File` then `new task run..` type in `explorer.exe` if you don't know how to open task manager after closing the explorer click ***Ctrl + left shift + Esc***

Comment: Hi, you reference many good debugging steps. However, “open a New Text Document and text on it from 100 to 500 letters” sounds like nonsense. If this actually does something, could you provide a reference? Also, your answer is somewhat incoherent. Perhaps if you work with someone on the clarify your answer can be expanded, made more useful, and made understandable.