# explorer.exe very high ram usage?

Tags: windows-10, memory

I've noticed that my ram usage is pretty high today. Turns out the culprit is explorer.exe according to the task manager
[image]

Pretty strange because I don't even have any file explorer windows opened right now. Various antivirus programs don't show anything suspicious.

my PC: Win10 64 bit, 32 gb of RAM total. Is there any way to know why is explorer eating so much ram? (860 mb)

Comment: Does it happen in a minimal boot configuration

Comment: I never tried it. But the thing I noticed is that it gradually increases RAM usage the more the computer stays on. If I restart the pc then the usage goes back to normal but slowly builds up

Comment: VMMap will give you a quick overview of the type of memory it's using https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/vmmap

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't tell me much though. I am not very familiar with how ram works. Could you please check it out and tell what you think?

http://puu.sh/q8Dyw/6438c40e6b.png

Comment: Looks like you've got so much RAM that nothing gets paged out.

Comment: I see, thanks. Just wanted to know if its not a memory leak or virus or whatever

Comment: @keklord So try?

Comment: Do you have a Samsung SSD with RAPID enabled? Do you have any actual problems or is this purely cosmetic?

Comment: Actually yes, I do use a Samsung EVO 850 250GB SSD with rapid enabled. How did you know?

This is purely cosmetic. I just noticed that 800mb ram usage for an explorer process is kinda high

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this is not an issue at all. Your system just has more RAM than it can make effective use of. Under those conditions, the system will not make any attempts to reduce RAM usage but instead try to use as much RAM as it possibly can. RAM is use it or lose it -- you can't save it for later.

If you don't have any evidence that this is a problem, it most likely isn't.

*Update:* You have RAPID mode enabled. This uses RAM for write caching. To avoid making RAM free just to have to allocate it again, RAM is only returned to the system when there is a reason to do so. So probably at one point there was a large amount of data being written that was cached. This RAM will be automatically shifted to a more important use in the future should that be necessary. If your system has so much RAM it never comes under memory pressure, lots of RAM may just get "left where it was", which improves performance dramatically because it avoids the need to have to make RAM free just to allocate it again.

Comment: Why would write caching cause `explorer.exe` to report high memory usage? Wouldn’t you expect this memory usage to show up under `System` or even not a process at all but as the cache portion of the Memory section under the Performance tab?

Comment: @binki The OP has 32GB of RAM and is complaining about high RAM usage. He reports explorer.exe using around 3% of his memory. So it can't be a significant factor in the OP's high RAM usage. (The rest of my answer primarily addresses use by explorer.exe itself.)

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 seams to have a memory leak issue in Explorer.

[image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6CRRMWk1IhBWi05YkYzb0diOXc/view]

[An user reported that](https://superuser.com/a/1103068/174557) installing [KB3172985](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3172985) which brings the OS Build to 10586.494 fixes his memory leak issue. So make sure your Windows 10 is up to date.

Comment: I actually had it installed  when this happened. Maybe they didn't fix it completely or it's something else

Comment: My Commit(KB) is up to 23,872,032, which seems a bit high (Working Set is just 113,176 KB, though). I'm wondering if that KB will help my system.

Comment: @ssmith this is not too much. those are normal values

Comment: 23GB of RAM is normal for explorer? (which then crashes) Really?